# C# How to open web page, identify element, input data and wait for next page?

Tags: c#, html, winforms

This question probably exist in different forms but I would need to get explained to me how to accomplish the following...

I'm working on a windows forms application (C#). When I click a button on the form I want to navigate to a specific page (all in code behind), find an input[type=text] on that page by id or class, input a password, and click on the login button next to the input.

Then I need to wait for the page that will load after the login button is clicked before I continue identifying more elements. F.e I want to find a html table and traverse it.

If someone could give me a good example and tell me if I need any additional controls in my form I would be most grateful.

Now, as I wrote above, I'm not interested in opening a browser and navigating to that page. I want it all to take place in the code so to speak..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a WebBrowser class (not a Control) to navigate to the login address, insert the values in the input fields, `InvokeMember("click")` on the `Submit` element, then use the `DocumentDownloadCompleted` event to determine when the new page has been loaded. You'll have to handle multiple events: when you first load the login page (which, hopefully, will raise the event just once), then when the landing page is loaded (it may raise the event multiple times). Use the `ReadyState` flag to determine when the Main Document has been downloaded completely.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to scrape the website and find the input of `type=text`. Forms works with `GET` or `POST` requests. Login form is generally a `POST` request to the server, you should search for the form inside that page and see where it points the action. Let's say it is done this way:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
```

So you know that `login.php` will handle the request and that it's using the `post` method.

Now you should write some `C#` code to send a `POST` request to `http://yoururl.com/login.php` (Please see [`HttpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

Once you get that, since it's a login, you should find a way to keep cookies active so that you can send another request to the page you have to access after the login. Keeping cookies active means that you're logged and your session is active with the user you logged in the previous `POST` request.

To achieve this part you should have a look to [`HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Once you get your cookies you should now send a `GET` request to the next page where you can then scrape the information you need. The `GET` request to a web page send you the whole html page as response. You should then use a scraping library such as [`HttpAgilityPack`](https://html-agility-pack.net/) to get the table you need.

Try to write some code and come back when you face a problem, opening another question. I hope I provided you some useful information!